# Prove that $R$ is a ring of subsets if and only if...

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, and let $R ⊆ P(X)$ be a collection (or set) of subsets of $X$. How can I prove that $R$ is a ring of subsets of $X$ if and only if $∅ ∈ R$ and for all $A, B ∈ R$, both $A ∩ B$ and $A \bigtriangleup B$ are in $R$? Is there a proposition or a book that anyone can recommend?

Comment: See the first two paragraphs of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structures)

Also, I think the condition $\emptyset\in R$ is redundant (edit: I guess this condition is given to ensure $R$ is non-empty). If $R$ is non-empty, we have $A\bigtriangleup A=\emptyset\in R$ where $A\in R$

Comment: Would this be a correct proof? - Let $R$ be a ring, then for $A,B \in R$ we have $A\cup B \in R$ and $A\setminus B \in R$. Given that $A \cup B = (A \bigtriangleup B) \bigtriangleup (A \cap B)$ and $A \setminus B = A \bigtriangleup (A \cap B)$, then we must have that $A\cap B \in R$ and $A \bigtriangleup B \in R$.